# Plural form of letters

Tags: gramática

What is the correct plural of single letters? I encountered three variants:

1. veinte **a's**, una b, dieciséis **c's**, trece **d's**, treinta **e's**,  dos **f's**, ... ([Source](http://www.math.northwestern.edu/~mlerma/))
2. dieciséis «**a**», una «b», quince «**c**», once «**d**», dieciocho «**e**», ... ([Source](http://www.juegosdepalabras.com/palabra2.htm))
3. **aes**, **bes**, **ces**, **des**, **es**, **efes**, ... ([Source](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2466329))

Are all of these forms correct?

Comment: Thanks @Diego and @guifa! I suspected that #3 is correct and that #1 is not, but I wasn't sure if #2 would be acceptable.

Comment: In Spanish the apostrophe should never be used for plural. And it is very questionable in English too, I think.

Comment: @rodrigo In English for single letters it is considered the norm in most style guides, mainly I think because *as/is/us* are all already words.

Comment: @guifa is right, many sources in English use apostrophes due to ambiguity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'll go with #3:

> Las vocales forman su plural añadiendo -es: a/aes, e/es (también ees), i/íes, o/oes, u/úes.
>
> A las consonantes, en cambio solo se les añade -s: be/bes, ce/ces, de/des, efe/efes, ge/ges, hache/haches, jota/jotas, ka/kas, ele/eles, eme/emes, ene/enes, eñe/eñes, pe/pes, cu/cus (de la letra “q”), erre/erres, ese/eses, te/tes, uve/uves, uve doble/uves dobles (doble u/doble ues en cierto paises), equis/equis (permanece igual), i griega/íes griegas (alternativamente ye/yes en ciertos países), zeta/zetas.

Source:
http://castellanoactual.com/el-plural-de-las-letras/

This is consistent with the RAE, which is **the** offical thing.
http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Iwao8PGQ8D6QkHPn4i

Comment: En el español del día al día, no sería muy común decir "aes", "ées" y "óes", "íes" y "úes" son más comunes pero aún así se acostumbra decirlo simplemente añadiendo una S, pero de manera escrita pues las normas son las normas.

Comment: El plural de *w* debe see *uves dobles*. Antiguamente — bueno, hace cuatro años — *y* era también *íes griegas*, y los dígrafos eran *ches* y *elles*

Comment: @guifa, corregido. Gracias.

Comment: Ese antiguamente aplica más en España porque en México y otros países se dice _doble u_ —nadie dice _doble ve_ o _uve doble_ y en plural _doble us_. Y la _i griega_, plural _i griegas_ coexiste con la _ye_ y _yes_. En matemáticas se usa siempre _ye_ e _i griega_ se acostumbra más a la hora de hablar de textos aunque no hay diferencia si se usa una u otra.

Comment: @JaimeCruzTriana, OK, actualizado tambien, aunque me queda la duda de si es "doble us" o "doble ues" o "dobles ues"...

Answer (score 5):

In addition to number #3 (which is the standard as Diego details), also acceptable would be

> seis letras *a*
>   ocho letras *m*
>   una letra *x*

In this construction, *letra(s)* becomes the primary noun, and *a/m/x* become juxtaposed nouns (and functions as an adjective) which obviates the need for pluralizing them since juxtaposed nouns are normally invariable in number.